# I got an error when i selected CORS of my api gate way

Tags: aws-lambda, python-3.7

I select "Enable CORS" in my AWS Lambda API Gateway and checked the checkbox "Default 4XX" but the operation fails with an "Unknown Error".

What is wrong with my steps?

[aws-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLxOG.png)

[error-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALn8m.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a default Status Code for 4XX responses. Afterwards, you can add the CORS headers using the "Enable CORS" functionality.

[image: Screenshot]